# How to enable AEB (automatic exposure bracketing) on canon camera using canon camera sdk?

Tags: camera, edsdk

I am using latest canon sdk version 2.11.
I want to set AE bracketing in Manual shooting mode. unfortunately with no luck.

I can see kEdsPropID_AEBracket property but have no idea what parameter value should be used to set levels.

does anyone know hot to set AEB in canon camera?

Comment: How did you get a hold of 2.11? I am in need of 2.11 but Canon USA hasn't released it yet, which is unfortunately driving me to purchase another lot of 5D MkII because of the lack of support for the MkIII.

Comment: well, I am using European site. https://www.didp.canon-europa.com seems like their rules are different for Europe and other counties.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can use the auto exposure bracketing in manual mode. In this mode you have to manual specify all parameters. To use auto exposure bracketing you need to be in either a full program mode, or either Aperture/Shutter priority mode.

Comment: well, if I set AEB in manual mode, me camera do a set of exposure bracket images. for example if I set Tv = 80, F=10, AEB = +-2 then I'll get 3 images with Tv=80, 15 and 320. this behavior is described in my 7D manual.

Comment: Tv is shutter priority mode, so you can in fact set an AEB from that mode. When I get to work I will update the answer with code to do that.